# Settext of ListView TextView

Tags: android, xml, listview, simplecursoradapter, layout-inflater

I am new to android programming so forgive me, when I don't know how to do this. I have been struggling with this for a very long time now, and I can't seem to figure out what my solution is.

In my Main `Activity` I have a `ListView`.

Looks like something like this:

Date    Kilometers    Location
14/7-17    100 km     Unknown
15/7-17    200 km     Unknown

I want to change the unit km, which isn't changed from my `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

My `TextView` from my `ListView` layout file `item_list.xml`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/kmListview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_km"
    android:text=" km"  />
```

This is the method I use in `Main.java` to populate the `ListView`

```
KilometerSQL listen = new KilometerSQL(this);
    listen.open();
    cursor = (Cursor) KilometerSQL.getSpinnerDatalist();

    SimpleCursorAdapter scaList = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            Main.this, 
            item_list,
            cursor,
            new String[] {KilometerSQL.KEY_DAY, KilometerSQL.KEY_MONTH, KilometerSQL.KEY_YEAR, KilometerSQL.KEY_KILOMETER, KilometerSQL.KEY_LOCATIONS, KilometerSQL.KEY_STARTKILOMETER, KilometerSQL.KEY_SLUTKILOMETER, KilometerSQL.KEY_ROWID},
            new int[]{R.id.itemDay,   R.id.item_month,   R.id.item_year,  R.id.item_km, R.id.itemLocation, R.id.startKilometerlist, R.id.stopKilometerlist, R.id.textView16},
            kmTypeInt);

   lv.setAdapter(scaList);

    listen.close();
```

So my question is, how can i change this little `TextView` from the `ListView` layout?

I have so far tried this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
    TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kmListview);
    t.setText("Miles");
```

But that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be lazy. Google provides an excellent documentation for a lot of components.
See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Or even better, try the new RecyclerView, that is an improved ListView.
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html